# Problem of Python running code error on Pycharm

Tags: python, json, windows, pycharm, tweetstream

I'm using Pycharm professional 2019.03 to execute Python code Streaming Twitter Filter. The running code finish unsuccessfully with message error :

Traceback (most recent call last):

```
File "C:/Users/HP/PycharmProjects/Twitter_Stream/twitter_filter.py", line 12, in <module>
    with open(file_path) as f:
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/config/api.json'
```

When I ran the script `print(os.getcwd())` the result is `C:\Users\HP\PycharmProjects\Twitter_Stream`
The Run/Debug configurations Windows show that the working directory is
`C:\Users\HP\PycharmProjects\Twitter_Stream` and all seem ok but I dont know why this message error. The `api.json` file is in the same directory than `twitter_filter.py`

I tried to replace the code :
`file_path = '/config/api.json' by file_path = '/Users/HP/PycharmProjects/Twitter_Stream/config/api.json'` or
`file_path = 'C:/Users/HP/PycharmProjects/Twitter_Stream/config/api.json'`,
I have this message error :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/HP/PycharmProjects/Twitter_Stream/twitter_filter.py", line 13, in <module>
    twitter_api = json.loads(f.read())
  File "C:\Users\HP\Anaconda3\lib\json\__init__.py", line 348, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "C:\Users\HP\Anaconda3\lib\json\decoder.py", line 337, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
  File "C:\Users\HP\Anaconda3\lib\json\decoder.py", line 353, in raw_decode
    obj, end = self.scan_once(s, idx)
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting property name enclosed in double quotes: line 3 column 5 (char 7)
```

Please someone can help me to solve thise problem? Let me know if you need more information

Thank you !

Comment: There's a problem with your json file formatting.

Comment: You say the `api.json` file is in the same directory as `twitter_filter.py`, but the file path you use has `config\` in it. Are you sure you have that correct?

Answer (score 0):

(I would comment but I do not have enough rep points.)

When you see the `JSONDecodeError`, it means the JSON file is successfully being read by the module.

However, it appears the module deems the file invalid.

From past experiences, I would check if the JSON file is valid with this link: https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/

I think what could be wrong is that your JSON file is using single quotes instead of double quotes, so not properly formatted.

Comment: In fact I think that my Json file is not properly formatted. This is my code :

Comment: Before to send you the code, I'm going to try to correct it!

Comment: XD okay, a simple `Replace (Ctrl. H)` to replace `'` for `"` should do!

Comment: The tools to valid Json formatting still show me problems on my file. Can you help me to fix that. This is the content of my file.{
    "consumer_key":'MhQGtweOFQNqeBRhumbcq69AS'
    "consumer_secret":'w98yHiKqDqmdHW8mpk5CvZsy1ytO7DF24DYMvNiaUtj1hPBE0g'
    "access_token":'1200185154825859078-qXArXtk6Fp7E9sy8JTaRke0y091QRt'
    "access_token_secret":'6cN7LetEWipraaZ1QZPWYs1lVTwQZdu8kY2lS0Kd5jksH'
}

Comment: Yes, and they would be correct to report such a thing. You are missing commas after every entry. For example, you would need to `{"key1": "value1", "key2": "value2"}`. You are missing the comma between `"value1"` and `"key2"`.

Comment: The problem of json file formatting is fixed, I get the same error like before.

Comment: That's odd, did you make sure to validate your JSON again? Send it again, perhaps?

Comment: I tried ones again there is no error ! Thank you a lot.

Comment: @Ado Mark my answer as accepted? I could use the rep. Thanks!